# Convert numeric value to date in Java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert numeric string  value in to date.

My code is

```
String input =  "1537011000";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMM").parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy").format(d);
System.out.println("output = " + output);
```

**but I'm not able to convert. I'm getting an `Exception:
Unparseable date: "1537011000"`

**Expected result is 15th September**

Comment: What does "1537011000" stand for? Number of (milli)seconds since some starting point? Look like seconds (and not milliseconds) since 01/01/1970

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have Epoch seconds in your value, so you can use `new Date(long)` using the long representation of that value times 1000:

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(input) * 1000);
```

That sets `d` to `Sep 15th`

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMM").parse(input)` parses a string `input` which should contain a date formatted in a given format, in your case "ddMMMM". So it expects something like "18Sept" (where 18 is a year) and not the Epoch time. You have to convert the epoch time into data and then print it in a desired format.

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of seconds, Date uses ms. And the new date time classes (LocalDateTime) should be the prefered way.

```
    LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1537011000L, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Date d = new Date(1537011000L*1000);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(d);

2018-09-15T11:30
Sat Sep 15 13:30:00 CEST 2018
```

Comment: Or simpler yet: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_537_011_000)`; also preserves the offset information (and better to avoid the outdated and poorly designed `Date` class if possible).

Comment: @OleV.V. `Instant.ofEpochSecond` was my first thought also; indeed cleanest, though requires more overview, insight into using the many classes. `Date` was mentioned by the OP so s/ms problem mentioned.